# Error: Cannot find module './commands/banner.js'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, discord.js, ubuntu-16.04

I recently pushed my entire bot to a hosting service called "Vultr" and tried running my bot but I was encountered with the error: **Error: Cannot find module './commands/banner.js'** and I don't know why this is happening as it works perfectly fine locally on my pc. If anyone knows why this is happening and the solution please provide how to fix it. I have provided images below to help.

Thanks, Gianni.

In my ubuntu terminal:

[image]

The code:

[image]

FileZilla directory: (Both commands folders have the javascript files)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Filezilla the folder name at `Mythra` is `Commands`, not `commands` (as written in your code). If that is a Linux server, folders are case sensitive unlike Windows machines which ignore case.

I would fix the folder names on your local machine and repush the site. If I remember right you can't simply change the name only by case, it doesn't keep. You need to change the folder to a different name then to what you want. For example:
Commands -> cCommands -> commands

Comment: I have never had experience with Linux so thank you informing me. I'll make sure to mark your answer as correct when possible.